# call js code in User control from page using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, controls

I have a js method in a common user control that is being used across the project. This `UserControl` is used in multiple places on my page.
The js method is written like :

```
function <%= this.ClientID%>DoSomething()
{
//do something
}
```

Is there a way I can call this method from the parent page using jquery?

Any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: it is not a best practice to use this kind of function names

Comment: yes, I know but I didn't write this and it is being used now. :)

Comment: it may used now, but you can refactor if you want ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the `<%= this.ClientID%>` so that should be saved somewhere.

```
window.clientID = "<%= this.ClientID%>";
```

to call the function you can try something like

```
window[window.clientID + "DoSomething"]()
```

Because the functions are saved to the document, you can access them as you do to a normal array. Normally you can call them like `window.doSomething()` or `doSomething()` which results in the same.

**Working version**

```
window.myFunction = function()
{
     alert("YEAH");  
}

window.clientID = "my";
alert(window[window.clientID + 'Function']);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EbdwK/

Comment: The global object is `window`, not `document`. So it should be `window[document.clientID + 'DoSomething']`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I made a mistake.

Comment: I have the user controls in my page inside divs with class "test".
Can I get the clientid of the user controls by iterating over all divs with class "test"?

Comment: You can do `$(".test").each()` and then get the `.attr("id")` if that is the clientID

Answer (score 0):

### Of course

Your method (JavaScript method defined in UserControl) is theoretically can be called easily from anywhere, as long as you can find it on the client side, and it's already defined.

Now, in your UserControl, you can expose a public parameter to the outside world (Page for example) and in your page, you can get that parameter from user control, then build the call for the JavaScript method.